# Selenium IE: 32 bit IEDriverServer doesn't load, and 64 bit text is slow

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am running the latest selenium code from Jenkins (3.5.3) and my tests are being sent via the grid to a VM node running Windows Server 2012.  If I try to to run IEDriverServer 64 bit (3.5.1) on my node, the sendkeys is unbearably slow.  I have read numerous times that using the 32 bit IEDriverServer would work, but it doesn't even load IE when I execute the tests.

The crazy thing is, this worked for 9 hours yesterday (I have hundreds of tests, this is the correct timeframe).  When I went to re-run the tests again today, they started out fine but then after a few hours I noticed that my tests weren't passing, so I checked the VM and the text was crawling. Why would something like this happen?  I understand in theory that the slow sendkeys is because of a bitness mismatch, but why would the 64 bit exe work for hours and then stop working?

For whatever it's worth, here is my webdriver definition:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
                .destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), ieOptions.merge(caps));
return driver;
```

I've been researching and trying to fix this for off and on for weeks.  It's driving me crazy.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much!

Edit: Looking at the test where it started to slow down, it turns out I deleted a cookie in that test.  From what I read about IE, it doesn't always handle deleting cookies correctly.  I can easily re-write that test, but now the text is always running slowly no matter what test is being ran.  Has anybody every encountered this?

(Side node: I hate IE.  That is all).